# Android Volume down key press causing ANR in my application

Tags: java, android

During testing , i got a issue , when repeadly press volume down key, my application prompt with ANR dialog. I am not handling any input key event in my activity.

Logs
Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{71f775 token=Token{2123aeac ActivityRecord{332f745f u0 com.test/.uis.CallActivity t766}}}.  It has been 5006.8ms since event, 5003.3ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.
04-06 16:54:34.885: I/WindowManager(1633): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{71f775 token=Token{2123aeac ActivityRecord{332f745f u0

Code
  final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.dimAmount = 0.0f; // Dim level. 0.0 - no dim, 1.0 - completely
                                 // opaque
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);

```
    getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: Please provide complete logs. 
Are you sure that you are not using any service or inheriting any class that may be using those events?

Comment: Don't just show an error log - show code which is causing it.

Comment: Added more code, suspect for ANR. I am not using any of those events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what was happening in logs 5 seconds before this log came

> ActivityRecord{332f745f u0 com.test/.uis.CallActivity t766}}}. It has
>   been 5006.8ms since event, 5003.3ms since wait started. Reason:
>   Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application
>   that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up

Specially check for Input events(Logs from InputDispatcher or InputReader). This might give a clue. Sometimes, this can happen if your system is heavily loaded(RAM space) and you are giving events at a high rate.

> I would also suggest you to do below things:
>
> 1. Can you try the same operation by keeping any other application in foreground.
> 2. Please try to check on some other device in case you have not checked on any other device.(just to make sure this is your app
>      problem).

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply. And one more update I am using invisible activity by setting width and height attribute to 0 dp. and trying to display it while screen is lock. getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                ); and intent to start it contain Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag.